# jQuery not running correctly on Joomla

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

I am working on a website and I cannot find the reason why the jQuery code doesn't show as it shows on my local server, without using Joomla.
I am using Joomla 2.5.1 and I am trying to run the following piece of code on this website: **http://www.elitartravel.com**

**Code:**

```
<script>
(function(a){if(typeof define==='function'&&define.amd){define(['jquery'],a)}else{a(jQuery)}}(function($){if($.support.cors||!$.ajaxTransport||!window.XDomainRequest){return}var n=/^https?:\/\//i;var o=/^get|post$/i;var p=new RegExp('^'+location.protocol,'i');$.ajaxTransport('* text html xml json',function(j,k,l){if(!j.crossDomain||!j.async||!o.test(j.type)||!n.test(j.url)||!p.test(j.url)){return}var m=null;return{send:function(f,g){var h='';var i=(k.dataType||'').toLowerCase();m=new XDomainRequest();if(/^\d+$/.test(k.timeout)){m.timeout=k.timeout}m.ontimeout=function(){g(500,'timeout')};m.onload=function(){var a='Content-Length: '+m.responseText.length+'\r\nContent-Type: '+m.contentType;var b={code:200,message:'success'};var c={text:m.responseText};try{if(i==='html'||/text\/html/i.test(m.contentType)){c.html=m.responseText}else if(i==='json'||(i!=='text'&&/\/json/i.test(m.contentType))){try{c.json=$.parseJSON(m.responseText)}catch(e){b.code=500;b.message='parseerror'}}else if(i==='xml'||(i!=='text'&&/\/xml/i.test(m.contentType))){var d=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');d.async=false;try{d.loadXML(m.responseText)}catch(e){d=undefined}if(!d||!d.documentElement||d.getElementsByTagName('parsererror').length){b.code=500;b.message='parseerror';throw'Invalid XML: '+m.responseText;}c.xml=d}}catch(parseMessage){throw parseMessage;}finally{g(b.code,b.message,c,a)}};m.onprogress=function(){};m.onerror=function(){g(500,'error',{text:m.responseText})};if(k.data){h=($.type(k.data)==='string')?k.data:$.param(k.data)}m.open(j.type,j.url);m.send(h)},abort:function(){if(m){m.abort()}}}})}));

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "http://www.e-tsw.com/Search/Box?af=AF-ASB&ln=ESP&cu=PE",
        success: function (data) {
            jQuery("#liquidBoxContainer").html(data);
        }
    });
</script>
```

The lightbox shows faulty when ran on the webserver, as you can see. But when I run it on Xampp, and without using Joomla, it works just fine. Also, I installed a plugin to force the 2.1.4 version of jQuery to run, as I thought it was conflicting with the 1.8 jQuery version that the Joomla was running, but it didn't solve anything.

Can somebody tell me why is this happening? Maybe some of you might have encountered some similar problems with jQuery and Joomla.

Thank you.

Comment: There are several console errors just when loading that page.  Did you investigate any of them?  `"Can't find variable: jQuery"` seems like a pretty important one.

Comment: Hmm.. I am having some errors, but that is none of them, at least not on my side.

Comment: I keep getting the jQuery is not defined error. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery.fancybox is loaded before jquery, because this is joomla you need to either change the order that the extensions are loaded that add the js to the page or write a plugin to reorder the js includes before the page is rendered.